# starting flask app hides console output?

Tags: python, flask

Why does in this code

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("Hello!")   # this gets printed to the console
    x = input("Please type something: ") # this gets shown in the console
    print ("something never to be seen") # this does not get printed
    print (x) # neither
    app.run(port=5001)
```

the part printed after the input statement never get shown in the console?

This is what my console looks like:

```
$python flask2.py
Hello!
Please type something: asdf
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5001/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Appears as if starting the flask server somehow "hides" parts of the printed stuff?

Comment: It shows up for me (Python3.6/windows)

Comment: Is it possible that those lines *are* being displayed, just not in the location you expect (e.g. lower on the screen)?  I ask because print writes to stdout and flask writes to stderr -- these two can often get jumbled up regardless of the location in your code.

Comment: Indeed, problem does not happen when running from CMD, but in my case showed up when using Git Bash. Solved now - buffering issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard output is *buffered*, which means that print() statement output is not necessarily shown unless you call `sys.stdout.flush()`

Comment: spot on. Note that buffering on Windows does not occur (in my example) when running python from the cmd, but it does occur when using Git Bash.

Comment: Yes, buffering behavior is "unspecified", which means a print without a flush might work fine on one OS, and not on another (or even another version of the same OS).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can reach that by using flask [Logging](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/logging/) module, and use `logger` replace `print`.

The `logging` module is more flexible than `print` statement. And you will find that the output you see right now(to stdout) is also controlled by `logging` module.

Here is an example of logging [INFO] level messages into a file and stdout. And if you want to "print" something you don't want to see in console, you can use `logger.debug('debug level msgs won't display in [INFO] level logger.')`

```
from logging.config import dictConfig

dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'file_fmt': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] - %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s',
        },
        'console_fmt': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'error.log',
            'formatter': 'file_fmt',
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'console_fmt',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout',
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'handlers': ['file', 'console']
    }
})
```

If you want to see [DEBUG] messages in console, just change `['handlers']['config']['level']` to `'DEBUG'`.